# Is the inverse of an $\alpha$-Hölder function a $\beta$-Hölder function, for some $\beta$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, dynamical-systems

I have a linearization of an one-dimensional map, given by the Hartman-Grobman Theorem:

$\pi = H^{-1} \circ \lambda\circ H$.

I know that $H$ is $\mathcal{C}^{1,\alpha}$.

Can I say that $H^{-1}$ is $\beta$-Hölder, for some $\beta$?

Comment: would $H(x) = x^3$ be a counterexample?

Comment: More generally, if $H$ is $\alpha$-Holder with constant $C_1$ and $H^{-1}$ is $\beta$-Holder with constant $C_2$, don't you get $|x-y|^{1 - \alpha \beta} \le C_1 C_2$ for arbitrary $x,y$ by writing $x = HH^{-1}(x)$ and similarly for $y$? this seems like a problem in general.